# How to debug a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this converter

```
public class SelectedItemsTipoArchivoRipsToObservable : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var SelectedItems = value as IList;
        List<MyType> Seleccionados = SelectedItems.Cast<MyType>().ToList();
        return Seleccionados;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I use it to convert `ListView.SelectedItems` to  `List<T>` and I'm using this XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="LstTiposArchivos" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TiposDeArchivos}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SeleccionarArchivosCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LstTiposArchivos,Path=SelectedItems,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=SelectedItemsToObservable}}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
           .....
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And in my `ICommand` execute:

```
public void ExecuteSeleccionarArchivos(object p)
{
    TiposDeArchivosaProcesar = (List<MyType>)p;
}
```

I have two questions:

1- How can I do to debug my converter? Reason: I have a breakpoint on it, but it only stops when the window is initializated.

2- Why this converter always returns an empty List (Count is always 0)?

Comment: Why you need a converter at first place? You can cast the collection in command execute method itself. Anyhow you are doing it by `(List<MyType>)p)` in command execute method.

Comment: Because it trhow a Cast error if I try to do it in command, My DelegateCommand class allways return object as parameter.

Comment: You should be able to debug your converter, like any other code, but you must ensure that it's run. I can't see where you have declared it. But I would rather do a <ListView.Resources><local:SelectedItemsToObservable x:Key="local:SelectedItemsToObservable"/></ListView.Resources>. Or declare it in the resources in the top of your view. <UserControl.Re... <Page.Re... or similar. Then change the binding to .. Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemsToObservable}.  Use ObservableCollection<T> instead of List, and make sure to use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise it on your props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first place you don't need converter at all.

If all you want to typecast SelectedItems collection to list of your type, you can do directly in command execute handler like this:

```
TiposDeArchivosaProcesar = (p as IList).Cast<MyType>().ToList();
```

You can also do safety checks in the method if you anticipate value other than your list.

```
var list = p as IList;
if(list != null)
{
   TiposDeArchivosaProcesar = list.OfType<MyType>().ToList();
}
```

---

Now, for your questions:

> How can I do to debug my converter? Reason: I have a breakpoint on it,
>   but it only stops when the window is initializated.

SLaks is partly right. Issue is not with property **TiposDeArchivosaProcesar** but with **SelectedItems**.

I just cross checked, **SelectedItems is not a Dependency property** whereas **SelectedItem** is a DP which means you can bind to SelectedItem but not with SelectedItems.

For converter to fire it needs some kind of notification that bounded value has changed but since SelectedItems is not a DP and not an **`INPC`** property. So, whenever it's changed no notification is raised. Hence, converter never hits again.

> Why this converter allways returns an empty List (Count is allways 0)?

Converter will be hit only once when your window will be initialized. And at that time SelectedItems collection was empty.

Comment: yes Thats true, But this doesn't make my View model dependent on view ?  And my first question maybe you could lead me a litle?

Comment: How come it's dependent? You are not accessing any view specific thing in your ViewModel.

Comment: Just i'm thinking about SelectedItems is a property of a visual Control. am i wrong ?

Comment: I have updated answer for your two questions as well. And regarding for your above comment, in command method all you getting is an object. So, I don't think it's violation of MVVM in any manner.

Comment: Very tks for your help, Better explained impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Your property (SelectedItems) isn't a DependencyProperty and doesn't raise `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Therefore, when you set the property, WPF never finds out.

Comment: @RohitVats: `TiposDeArchivosaProcesar` probably isn't.

Comment: Agree with @RohitVats My Command Allways execute en each change of SelectedItems. I'm not exposing **TiposDeArchivosaProcesar** I need to convert SelectedItems and store it into **TiposDeArchivosaProcesar**

Comment: @Slaks - OP issue is converter is not getting hit. `TiposDeArchivosaProcesar` is just local field of handler. It's no where binded to UI. So, why it needs to raise `PropertyChanged` event?